# What do I have to consider in an multiview-application, when it comes to low memory warnings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uikit

Somewhere I was reading that I would run into memory problems when I give up a view temporary due to an low memory warning (loading it again as soon as the user wants to see it), if theViewController class does not do things like this on every outlet of that view:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [myView release], myView = nil;
    [myLabel release], myLabel = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I am confused here, because actually I thought that [myView release] would also make the nil-thing, saying that variable holds no object anymore. Why twice? Or is there something I missed?

Answer (score 5):

Calling `[myView release]` doesn't change the value of `myView`, it decrements the retain count of the object that `myView` points to (and when the retain count of an object goes to zero, it `dealloc`s itself).  After calling `[myView release]`, `myView` still contains the address of the view object, but if `myView` was the only owner, that object has `dealloc`ed itself and the memory is no longer valid (and my now be occupied by another object or other data).  By setting `myView` to `nil`, you make sure that you don't accidently use the old memory that used to belong to `myView`, and you can now test if `myView` has been initialized or discarded.

Note that you don't need to set `myView` to `nil` in your `-dealloc` method, since your view controller is going away at this point anyway, but you would want to do this if you discard your view in response to a low memory warning.  You might also consider discarding the whole view controller if its view isn't visible.

Comment: thanks. So in case of an low memory warning, I would write [myView release], myView = nil; right inside that low memory warning eventhandler-method? Or would self.myView = nil just work the same way?

Comment: Assuming your @property myView is defined as retain or copy, either way would work.

Answer (score 0):

When a view controller gets a memory warning, and the view is off-screen, it may set the view property to nil. But that won't release any subviews that you might be retaining in other properties. So here's how you can handle that:

```
- (void)setView:(UIView *)view
{
  [super setView:view];
  if (view == nil)
  {
    // Release-and-nil any subviews that you might be retaining.
  }
}
```